# 503 Service Unavailable after 60 seconds Apache Symfony (in certain features only)

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd, fpm

I currently face an issue in a Symfony 3.4 application, in one of its features which loads history of some data (a lot of data actually which dates from 2017).

When trying to access the history feature, the GET HTTP request keeps loading for 60 seconds exactly, then a 503 service unavailable shows up, same issue happens in other features that loads big number of data.

Checked the logs, application logs and server (Apache) logs, only Apache logs shows 503 code with no details.

I suspected the `php.ini` configuration, and changed values of `max_execution_time` to -1 and `memory_limit` to 2048M, but still the GET HTTP request terminates after 60 seconds exactly.

I also use `php-fpm` and checked the `www.conf` and it doesn't have anything that overrides the values of `php.ini`. I even added `request_terminate_timeout = 600s` to only see if the value will be taken into consideration but still the same issue, GET HTTP request of the history terminates exactly after 60 seconds of loading (waiting).

I make sure to restart `php-fpm` and `httpd` (Apache) after the changes in the configuration file.

The os system is **Redhat**,

Database server is working fine, since I can access other data in other features.

Expected behavior:

I expected at least the GET HTTP request to keep loading for more than 60 seconds, other than that it means I still didn't find the correct parameter.

Logs from `ssl_access_log`: `ip - - date "GET /p/a/h HTTP/1.1" 503 299`

Comment: An HTTP 503 error is "Service Unavailable" and can happen when a backend proxy does not produce data before the web server times out.  The web server would have no knowledge of what happened as it could not connect with the backend service, so you would need to check the logs from the proxy (PHP-FPM in this case).  You should also check the `TimeOut` or `ProxyTimeout` options in the Apache configuration.

Comment: Thanks @GracefulRestart, will check the logs and get back to you, thank you for your time.

Comment: Logs aren't activated for php-fpm and also the TimeOut & ProxyTimeout in Apache configuration arent set.

Comment: Not set means it uses the default value.  The [default `Timeout` for Apache is 60 seconds](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout) so you would likely want to raise that to a value that allows your PHP-FPM enough time to process.

Comment: Hi @GracefulRestart, You were right, I had to explicitly add TimeOut with an increased number above 60 to break the 60 seconds timeout.
Now the GET HTTP request works and the problem is no longer present, 
Many thanks for your time and your help, really appreciated, wish best of luck in your life.